# Visual basic 2010 send email using gmail SMTP

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, email, smtp, gmail

I want to send email from my Visual basic form

my code:

```
   Private Sub email1()
    Try
        Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient
        Dim e_mail As New MailMessage()
        Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        Smtp_Server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("MYEMAIL@gmail.com", "MYPASS")
        Smtp_Server.Port = 465
        Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = True
        Smtp_Server.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"

        e_mail = New MailMessage()
        e_mail.From = New MailAddress("MYEMAIL@gmail.com")
        e_mail.To.Add("MYFRIENDEMAIL@gmail.com")
        e_mail.Subject = "SUBJECT"
        e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
        e_mail.Body = "TEXT MESSAGE"
        Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)


    Catch error_t As Exception
        email_status.Text = ("Error: " & error_t.Message)
        MsgBox(error_t.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    email_status.Text = ("OK")
End Sub
```

errors while using smtp.gmail.com

while using SMTP port 465: The operation has timed out.

while using SMTP port 587: Failure sending email.

while using SMTP port 25: Failure sending email.

---

errors while using smtp.googlemail.com

while using SMTP port 465: The operation has timed out.

while using SMTP port 587: Failure sending email.

while using SMTP port 25: Failure sending email.

---

i am using AVAST antivirus but i turned it off

can you please help me?

thank you very much.

Comment: Try setting `Smpt_Server.EnableSsl = false`. Or commented out and see if you can send the email.

Comment: Try setting your port to `587` and make sure your `firewall` is not blocking it.

Comment: windows firewall and AVAST .. completly off ... error: Failure sending email. (with both EnableSsl = false or true)

Comment: i try this code on another PC and it works!!! so problem is in my PC or my ISP .. sorry and thank you for your time :)